# Saxon: SetParameter to xpath expression

Tags: xslt, saxon

In my stylesheet i have a global datetime param with a default value of the current dateTime:

```
<xsl:param name="utcNow" select="current-dateTime()" as="xs:dateTime" />
```

For the purposes of unit testing I would like to change this param to an xpath of a node within the source document e.g.:

```
<xsl:param name="utcNow" select="//header/creationdate" as="xs:dateTime" />
```

However i am unable to find a successful way to use the SetParameter method (.NET) to change the param to an xpath. I can only find examples of setting the param to a static value? e.g.

```
xsltTransformer.SetParameter(new QName("", "utcNow"), new XdmAtomicValue("//header/creationdate"));
```

which results in the utcNow param holding a literal string value of "//header/creationdate"; not the evaluated xpath.

I could load the source document in .NET, xpath to the node, get the value, and set the parameter using the result, but that seems overkill. Is it possible to set the parameter to an xpath expression?

Update:
This is for XSLT 2.0, and saxon 8.

Comment: Do you need to change that path on different runs of the stylesheet? Your example `<xsl:param name="utcNow" select="//header/creationdate" as="xs:dateTime" />` should do what you say you want to do, namely select the value from the node of the primary source document. (I am not quite sure whether the `as="xs:dateTime" suffices, `select="xs:dateTime(//header/creationdate)"` seems the safer way). If you want a path you can change then a static parameter can help, I will try to put that in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use a version of Saxon that supports XSLT 3.0 (should be 9.8 or later, supported version is 10), a static parameter with a shadow attribute might help/suffice e.g.

```
<xsl:param name="xpath" as="xs:string" static="yes" select="'xs:dateTime(//header/creationdate)'"/>

<xsl:param name="utc-creation" _select="{$xpath}"/>
```

In the Saxon 10 .NET API make sure you set the **static parameter** **before compiling the stylesheet**, i.e. use https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation10/dotnetdoc/Saxon/Api/XsltCompiler.html#SetParameter(QName,XdmValue) on the `XsltCompiler`, according to the documentation the method is also available in 9.9 https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation9.9/dotnetdoc/Saxon/Api/XsltCompiler.html#SetParameter(QName,XdmValue) and 9.8 https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation9.8/dotnetdoc/Saxon/Api/XsltCompiler.html#SetParameter(Saxon.Api.QName,Saxon.Api.XdmValue).

Another option is the use of `xsl:evaluate` with e.g.

```
<xsl:param name="xpath" as="xs:string" select="'xs:dateTime(//header/creationdate)'"/>

<xsl:param name="utc-creation" as="xs:dateTime">
  <xsl:evaluate context-item="/" xpath="$xpath"/>
</xsl:param>
```

This is supported in Saxon HE since version 10.

Comment: I am using an older version of the saxon library where the setparameter method is on the XsltTransformer.
using `xsltTransformer.SetParameter(QName name, XdmValue value)` always results in the param being updated with the literal string of the xpath, not the evaluated result.

Comment: @Phil, I have edited the answer to explain which versions XSLT 3 static parameters should be supported with (although I have not checked now if the Saxon 9.8 or 9.9 API has it, I think it should). Saxon versions before 9.8 supported XSLT 2 but not 3 and static parameters and shadow attributes are certainly not supported in XSLT 2.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a very ancient version of Saxon, so memories are fading: "Saxon 8" could be any release from 8.0 to 8.9 so between about 2004 and 2010). However, there's probably some API for evaluating an XPath expression to return an XdmValue. Use that API to get a value, then pass the result into the SetParameter method.